Please review my usb lipo charging circuit
I've followed a tutorial on YouTube on how to make a USB charging and powering circuit for some mobile device. I decided to change up some parts because they were either too expensive or had too many features for what I was looking for. I have no idea if what I threw together works, I tried my best to follow the documentation but I'm new and kinda lost.
bottom left is for charging
top right is the regulator/boost converter
bottom right is the power switching.
Questions:
-I know I'm supposed to isolate the ground from the boost converter but I'm not sure what the best way to do that is.
-If the documentation for the battery charging requires a 1uf capacitor but the USB area already had it. Would I still need to add that capacitor? I'll probably put them right next to each other anyway.
-How will I trace the data pins from the USB area to where I need it to go? I know switching regulators can create noise, how important is that?
-Are the Ic's I chose any good?


If Vbat is present but Vcc isn't, the body diode of Q1 will pass Vbat-0.7 V into Vcc. If your boost converter U3 happy with that?

Unlike a lot of others, this particular charging IC requires you to terminate the charging when complete. From the datasheet: "The charge cycle is terminated by removing the battery from the charger, removing input power, or driving the
charge enable input (CE) to a logic Low. An automatic charge termination method is not implemented."

@winny I want Vbat to enter Vcc into the boost converter when Vdd/Vcc aren't present. That mosfet is there to have Vbat power the circuit when the USB is disconnected.

@Finbarr Thanks, I didn't see that, I switched to an IC that has that functionality.

That will probably mean the input side of the boost converter as well will receive voltage via the body diodes of U3.
